# ASP.NET MVC Layout not working without URL routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing strange behaviour for _Layout.cshtml

I have created a _Layout.cshtml for my project, it's working fine for Default rout i.e /Home/Index
then I have another controller named Biz wth action Categories, when I create the view for it using _Layout and run the project
all the content was displayed without any style and URL in the browser was localhost:54124/Biz/Categories.
when I configured rout in RouteConfig.cs file
as

```
    routes.MapRoute(
           name: "DT_FAP_Default",
           url: "Categories",
           defaults: new { controller = "Biz", action = "Categories", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

the layout is working fine

anybody have idea, what i am missing here?

I don't want to configure route for each action as my project has too many actions

Am facing same issue for other projects too. do I need any global configuration for vs?

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found the solution

I changed the css linking code

Old:

```
<link id="layout-theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/themes/dark-blue.min.css" />
```

New:

```
<link id="layout-theme" rel="stylesheet" href="@(Url.Content("~/assets/themes/dark-blue.min.css"))" />
```

Comment: That should not make a difference (unless you are using an old version of Razor web pages)